# JWT Bearer Authentication doesn't work on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I implemented a JWT Authentication on asp.net core 6 web API, from debugging using visual studio all works perfectly, when I published it on IIS , the Authenticate method on the Authenticate Controller gives Internal Server Error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DMDL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tGY2.png)

Program.cs

```
    using BackendDataLibrary.Models;
    using BackendDataLibrary.Repositories;
    using ELDataManagementLibrary;
    using ELDataManagementLibrary.Repositories;
    using ELDataManagementWebAPI.Services;
    using ELDataManagementWebAPI.Services.AuthenticationManager;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.Json;

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PasswordsService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ProfilesService>();



builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x => {
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    //x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretTokenKey"])),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
       ValidateAudience = false,
       // ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero

    };
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthenticationManager>(new JwtAuthenticationManager(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretTokenKey"]));

string ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ELTeamDatabase"];
var conStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
conStrBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Username"];
conStrBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Password"];
ConnectionStringHandler CSH = new ConnectionStringHandler(conStrBuilder.ConnectionString);


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

JwtAuthenticationManager

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BackendDataLibrary.Cryptography;
using BackendDataLibrary.Models;
using BackendDataLibrary.Services;
using ELDataManagementLibrary.ELDataManagementLibrary;
using ELDataManagementLibrary.Repositories;


namespace ELDataManagementWebAPI.Services.AuthenticationManager
{
    public class JwtAuthenticationManager : IJwtAuthenticationManager

    {

        private readonly string key;

        public JwtAuthenticationManager(string tokenkey)
        {
            this.key = tokenkey;

        }

        public Profile Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            Profile? profile = Pool.Instance.Profiles.GetChunk(1,"",1,$"UserName='{username}' and Status!=-100").SingleOrDefault();
            if (profile==null || !HashingHelper.VerifyPassword(password, profile.PasswordHash))
            {
                return null;
            }
 

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, profile.Role)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(profile.TimeOut),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
                    )
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            profile.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return profile;
        }


    }
}
```

Authenticate Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ELDataManagementWebAPI.Services.AuthenticationManager;
using ELDataManagementLibrary.Repositories;

namespace ELDataManagementLibrary.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticateController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IJwtAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager;

        public AuthenticateController(IJwtAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager)
        {
            this.jwtAuthenticationManager = jwtAuthenticationManager;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] UserCredential userCred)
        {
            var profile =this.jwtAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(userCred.UserName, userCred.Password);

            if (profile == null)
                return Unauthorized();
            return Ok(profile);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Any time you get an internal server error, you need to actually find out what the real error is. Attach a debugger or add sufficient logging to your app in order to capture the error details. Only once you know the error details can you begin addressing the root cause of the problem. Otherwise you'll just be guessing, and that's not a very efficient use of time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what the issue is without any error messaging.

But, some things to check:

1. Try `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` maybe to try and see better error reporting.
2. Ensure that `Jwt:SecretTokenKey` is at least 16 characters long.
3. Try deploying a self-contained executable to IIS instead of a framework dependent one (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Comment: If it's hard to tell from the question what the problem is, then don't answer it. That just means the question lacks appropriate detail. You shouldn't just take random guesses.

Comment: @mason OP posted screenshots, relevant source code, and described the issue fine.  Given there are two most likely possibilities to the cause, and I listed them with another one to add exception page logging, I'd really like to see the guideline that says no answer should be given unless there is one specific, definitive answer and not two possible answers.

Comment: They did not describe the issue fine, because they failed to find the actual error message. There are a near infinite amount of reasons a particular piece of code can have an error - trying to answer without the actual error message means you may be addressing other problems than the actual problem behind the question. It's also a poor waste of our time to try to list out all the possible reasons.

Comment: As for why the question isn't valid without a clear error, see [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error"